# In what order does sftp.ListDirectory(sourcePath) download the files

Tags: c#, file, sftp

I am using using Renci.SshNet.Sftp to download files from an sftp server.

I just want to know will the files be listed and downloaded according to their names Alphabetically or will it be done in the manner they were added to the SftpServer? I need to download and pickup file based on time. So the file that was put on first will download first regardless of its name.

The code is below:

```
            using (SftpClient sftp = new SftpClient(sftpServer, config.UserName, sftpPassword))
            {
                sftp.Connect();

                var files = sftp.ListDirectory(config.SourceFilePath);

                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    if (!file.IsDirectory && fileExtensions.Any(s => file.Name.Contains(s)))
                    {
                        FileHelper.DownloadFile(sftp, file, config.DestinationFilePath);
                        FileHelper.DeleteFile(sftp, file, config.SourceFilePath);

                        validFiles.Add(file);
                    }
                }

                sftp.Disconnect();
            }
```

Comment: I wonder how is it faster writing this question and waiting for someone to reply than just running the code you already wrote

Comment: I dont have access to an sftp server at the moment. wont have it until a few more days.. I just want a confirmation on how the files are ordered.

Comment: If you want to operate on them in order, you have a couple of choices.

If you want to operate on them in a separate thread as they are downloaded, you could probably call files.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedOn) or something like that.  Depending on the Type of "files."  If this works, you will download in the order you want and it will be the most efficient solution.

Or you could download them all, hopefully preserving their attributes, and operate on all them in whatever order you want once you have them all.